# Why does this python script not get executed during the build phase?

Tags: python, docker, sqlite

So I have a project with the following directories:

```
/conf
  | /dev
  |   | /py
  |      | db_setup.py
  |      | Dockerfile
  | requirements.txt
/data
  | /streaming
        | # <= Here is where I want to create the sqlite .db file
.env
docker-compose.yml
```

and a .env file like this:

```
DB_ABS_PATH=/home/fs/data/streaming
DB_FILE_NAME=server-archive.db
```

and a docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: conf/dev/py/Dockerfile
    container_name: fs-py
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/home/fs
    ports:
      - ${SERVER_PORT_IN}:${SERVER_PORT_OUT}
```

and a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:3.9.16

WORKDIR /home/fs

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r conf/requirements.txt
RUN python conf/dev/py/db_setup.py # <= My question is about this line

ENTRYPOINT [ "tail", "-f", "/dev/null" ]
```

And the `db_setup.py` has the following content:

```
import sqlite3
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pathlib import Path
import os

load_dotenv(Path(".env"))

try:
    sqliteConnection = sqlite3.connect(Path(os.environ.get("DB_ABS_PATH"), os.environ.get("DB_FILE_NAME")))
    cursor = sqliteConnection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE files(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        original_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        actual_name VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
        created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
        deleted_at TIMESTAMP NULL
    );
    """)
    cursor.close()
except sqlite3.Error as err:
    print("Error while connecting to sqlite", err)
finally:
    if sqliteConnection:
        sqliteConnection.close()
```

Basically, I'm trying to setup a sqlite database during the build stage. But when I use the `docker compose build`, I can see that the target run step passes without failure, however, the `sqlite.db` file is not created. Furthermore, there's nothing wrong with the script itself, as I have executed the script standalone from the container's terminal, and it worked as expected. What could be causing this issue? Is there a work around or something that I'm missing?

Comment: @HansKilian I'm not sure what's your source, but I've always used env variables at build time. BTW, I tested the `Path(os.environ.get("DB_ABS_PATH"), os.environ.get("DB_FILE_NAME"))` and made sure that it's retaining the correct value. So that's not the issue.

Comment: Your `volumes:` line is hiding everything the image sets up in `/home/fs` and replacing it with content from the host.  Does deleting this line help?

Comment: @DavidMaze This actually worked! Thanks! But now, when I remove the `volumes: ` line from `docker-compose.yml`, the `sqlite.db` is created at the target location in the container, but now the container's `sqlite.db` and other files are not at sync with my host files, meaning, the `sqlite.db` file is not created in the host as well... Any suggestions?

Comment: If you don't want your container's environment to be isolated from the host, your system most likely already has Python installed, and you can [use a virtual environment](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#creating-a-virtual-environment) for this.  Mounting a volume always hides what's in the image, so you can't create some content in the Dockerfile but then have it actually be stored outside the container.